# Why it doesn't use the instance field directly, but assigns it to a local variable?

Tags: java

I'm reading the source of `java.util.concurrent.ArrayBlockingQueue`, and found some code I don't understand:

```
private final ReentrantLock lock;

public boolean offer(E e) {
    if (e == null) throw new NullPointerException();
    final ReentrantLock lock = this.lock;
    lock.lock();
    try {
        if (count == items.length)
            return false;
        else {
            insert(e);
            return true;
        }
    } finally {
        lock.unlock();
    }
}
```

Notice this line:

```
final ReentrantLock lock = this.lock;
```

Why it doesn't use `this.lock` directly, but assigns it to a local variable?

Comment: Personally, I would always make sure locks (and any fields can be made final) is made final.  This avoids the need for this.

Comment: @PeterLawrey it is final, see my answer and John Skeet's

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Could it be for **optimization** purposes?

Possibly a local variable could more easily be directly allocated to a register with a JIT compiler.

At least in Android, for the first versions of the API, accessing a local variable was cheaper than accessing an instance variable (can't speak for newer versions). It could be that plain Java is the same, and in some cases it makes sense to use a local.

Actually, found a [thread confirming this here](http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/core-libs-dev/2010-May/004165.html). Extract:

> It's a coding style made popular by Doug Lea. It's an extreme
>   optimization that probably isn't necessary; you can expect the JIT to
>   make the same optimizations. (you can try to check the machine code
>   yourself!) Nevertheless, copying to locals produces the smallest
>   bytecode, and for low-level code it's nice to write code that's a
>   little closer to the machine.

Comment: Some BlackBerry optimization guide also mentions that using local variables instead of instance variables is up to 4 times faster, not sure if their JVM does these kinds of optimization automatically (probably not, since it was separately mentioned). On newer Javas in desktop/server environments, I doubt it has much effect.

Comment: I'll say it's just Doug's quirkiness. Even without any optimization, the extra read is nothing compared to cost of lock/unlock; it is not going to show up on any measurement.

Answer (score 1):

Since it's just copying the reference and the lock is on the Object instead, and the Object is the same, it shouldn't matter.

The instance variable *lock* is also declared final, so really, I don't see any point in doing a reference copy.

As JRL pointed out is an optimization, but it's really such a tiny micro-optimization, that I still don't see much point doing it, especially for just one read.

Answer (score 0):

#### Better safe than sorry?

I guess, when writing fundamental libraries, you'd better go for the safest solution, if it's cheap enough. And this one is extremely cheap.

- Concerning performance, a local variable should be faster than a field access. I guess, any JVM worth its name will do such a trivial optimization(*) itself, but what about interpreted code and possibly C1 (the first, fast and low-quality compiler in Oracle JVM)? It won't make much difference, but the saved microseconds count for millions of users. What about Java running on exotic platforms with a JVM yet to be written...
- The `final` is not exactly final in reality. The field may get changed using reflection. I can't imagine any reason for doing this and anyone doing such funny things just gets what they deserve. OTOH debugging such problems may take days and *fool-proof programming is a good habit* when writing such a fundamental stuff.

---

(*) I believe to have read an article by someone reputable claiming the opposite, but I can't find it now.