# When does the creation of temporary helper variables make sense?

Tags: java

I'd like to know in which cases you would prefer to create some kind of "helper" variable to access a value that might be used 2 or more times in a method.

I came around this question during following snipped: what is better: two times accessing the `size` value of a `List`, or creating an `Integer` variable that holds the size of the list?

```
List<String> list;

private myIndexHelper() {
    if (list.size % 2 == 0) {
        return PREFIX + list.size;
    }
    return "";
}

private myIndexHelper() {
    int size = list.size;
    if (size % 2 == 0) {
        return PREFIX + size;
    }
    return "";
}
```

I know this might probably be over-optimization. But also in general (neglecting performance): would you rather access the list.size property numerus times, or create a variable that hold the size?

Comment: It makes sense when that list.size transforms into half of line of mumbo jumbo method calls. Also, you would rather call a method once, if that method is resource consuming.

Comment: Readability IMHO. For example `int documentLength` makes more sense than `list.size`.

Comment: It seems to be against the "don't repeat yourself" principle if you dont do it.

Comment: This is an optimization that makes no difference. However, in a multi-threaded design, using `list.size()` might produce different results each time it is called. By using a local reference the result will at least be consistent with the algorithm used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There us no "better" approach:

1. when you call `list.size` or a local `size` parameter it has the same performance
2. According to [*Doug Lea*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doug_Lea), [declaring a local parameter as `final`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3602014/why-are-method-parameters-reassigned-to-local-variables) might lead to performance improvement
3. The only aspect which is "easiness of use" is when you want a "shorter" parameter so by using: a local `size` parameter instead of `myListOfReallyNiceIntegers.size` would be easier to read/write (with for-loops etc).

Answer (score 0):

In this case I'd say readability, if it's readable then either way is fine.  If on the other hand it was

```
private myIndexHelper() {
    if (dataStricture.subDataStructure.list.size % 2 == 0) {
        return PREFIX + dataStricture.subDataStructure.list.size;
    }
    return "";
}
```

Then I'd go with the variable approach but otherwise it's no big deal.

If, however this was a loop or time critical method then calling list.size inside the loop (or inside the time critical method) would just waste extra time doing method calls and should be avoided.

Like I said though, in this code, no big deal.

Answer (score 0):

As there is usually plenty of memory available today it may be good to add a helper-variable, as it may increase readability of the code (although it depends, as I personally find function-calls more readable in such cases - unless they are like object.ref.function(object2.ref2.anotherFunction()) or worse).

I think it is also worth mentioning that sometimes it is a matter of good practice: when you use a value many times in a loop, and this value changes, it is better to have this value stored in a variable rather than re-calculate it every time (in a loop the actual number of processor operations may grow quite quickly.) Good compilers often detect such cases of re-calculating the same value in a loop and create a variable themselves, but it is not a good practice to depend on a compiler in case of efficiency. Especially if you can achieve it by just slightly changing the code.