# Reason behind an extra assignment to a variable in java.util.HashMap.values() implementation

Tags: java, collections, hashmap

I was just going through the  java.util.HashMap values implementation and I found the values() implementation in this way

```
 public Collection<V> values() {
        Collection<V> vs = values;
        if (vs == null) {
            vs = new Values();
            values = vs;
        }
        return vs;
    }
```

Why is an extra vs variable needed?

Why don’t it’s just

```
 public Collection<V> values() {
        if (values == null) {

            values =  new Values();     
     }
        return values;
    }
```

Is there any particular reason ? If anyone know the reason behind it please share it?

Comment: You can find the same idiom in many JDK classes.

Comment: This is also related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3602014/why-are-method-parameters-reassigned-to-local-variables